# How to use two data source for same entity in spring boot application running on tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have one micro-service named order-service in spring boot.

`:: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.5.RELEASE)`

in that micro-service, in service layer I have 2 service class 1. `OrderManagerService` and `OrderService`. From `OrderService` I call Repository Interface `IOrderRequestRepository` which extends `PagingAndSortingRepository` interface. so The call is basically `OrderManagerService` -> `OrderService` -> `IOrderRequestRepository`.

Right now I am using one data source for the micro-service. Now my requirement is I have to use 2 data source because in `OrderManagerService` there is one method `getCustomerVisitsForMonth(Long customerID)` which frequently used and we don't want to give load on prod DB server. Instead we will use prod-replica server for this one particular method.

I have googled a lot of blogs and tried to implement but ending up getting different exception.

below are exceptions:

```
could not execute query; SQL [SELECT * FROM ....(this is the actual query)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query",
```

```
Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed:
```

Below are my sample code:

**application-env.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://someurl:3306/orders?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=<username>
spring.datasource.password=<password>
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

#replica datasource details
spring.replica.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://someurl:3306/order?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&useSSL=false
spring.replica.datasource.username=<username>
spring.replica.datasource.password=<password>
spring.replica.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=15
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=20000
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=5
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=4
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=2
spring.datasource.tomcat.default-auto-commit=true

#replica data source details
spring.replica.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=15
spring.replica.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=20000
spring.replica.datasource.tomcat.max-active=5
spring.replica.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=4
spring.replica.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=2
spring.replica.datasource.tomcat.default-auto-commit=true
```

**Main class**

```
package in.demo.order.web.app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "in.demo.order",
    exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
public class OrderServiceApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(OrderServiceApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    return builder.sources(OrderServiceApplication.class);
  }
}
```

I have created 2 different packages for Repository classes and for Entity classes, however my Entity and Repository are same.

packages

1. `in.demo.order.dao`
2. `in.demo.order.repodao`

**Configuration classes**

`MainDataSourceConfiguration`

```
package in.demo.order.web.config;

import in.demo.order.replicadao.IOrderRequestRepositoryForReplica;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "in.demo.order.dao",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "mainEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "mainTransactionManager"
)
public class MainDataSourceConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "mainDataSourceProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties mainDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }


    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "mainDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.configuration")
    public DataSource mainDataSource(
            @Qualifier("mainDataSourceProperties") DataSourceProperties mainDataSourceProperties) {

        return mainDataSourceProperties
                .initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource.class)
                .build();
    }


    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "mainEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mainEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder mainEntityManagerFactoryBuilder,
            @Qualifier("mainDataSource") DataSource mainDataSource) {

        Map<String, String> mainJpaProperties = new HashMap<>();

        mainJpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect",
                environment.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect"));

        mainJpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                environment.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean = mainEntityManagerFactoryBuilder
                .dataSource(mainDataSource)
                .packages("in.demo.order.dao.model")
                .persistenceUnit("mainDataSource")
                .properties(mainJpaProperties)
                .build();

        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
    }


    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "mainTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager mainTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("mainEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory mainEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(mainEntityManagerFactory);
    }

}
```

`ReplicaDataSourceConfiguration`

```
package in.demo.order.web.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "in.demo.order.replicadao",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "replicaEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "replicaTransactionManager"
)
public class ReplicaDataSourceConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;
    
    @Bean(name = "replicaDataSourceProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.replica.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties replicaDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    
    @Bean(name = "replicaDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.replica.datasource.configuration")
    public DataSource replicaDataSource(
            @Qualifier("replicaDataSourceProperties") DataSourceProperties replicaDataSourceProperties) {

        return replicaDataSourceProperties
                .initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource.class)
                .build();
    }

    
    @Bean(name = "replicaEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean replicaEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder replicaEntityManagerFactoryBuilder,
            @Qualifier("replicaDataSource") DataSource replicaDataSource) {

        Map<String, String> replicaJpaProperties = new HashMap<>();

        replicaJpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect",
                environment.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect"));

        replicaJpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                environment.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean = replicaEntityManagerFactoryBuilder
                .dataSource(replicaDataSource)
                .packages("in.demo.order.replicadao.model")
                .persistenceUnit("replicaDataSource")
                .properties(replicaJpaProperties)
                .build();
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    
    @Bean(name = "replicaTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager replicaTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("replicaEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory replicaEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(replicaEntityManagerFactory);
    }

}
```

`OrderManagerService`

```
package in.demo.order.service;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@Transactional
public class OrderManagerService{

  @Autowired
  private OrderService orderService;

  public CustomerVisitsResponse getCustomerVisitsForMonthForReplicaDataSource(Long customerId) {
    return orderService.getTotalCustomerVisitsForMonth(customerId);
  }

  public CustomerVisitsResponse getCustomerVisitsForMonthForMainDataSource(Long customerId) {
    return orderService.getTotalCustomerVisitsForMonthForMainDataSource(customerId);
  }

}
```

`OrderService`

```
package in.demo.order.service;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


import in.demo.order.replicadao.IOrderRequestRepositoryForReplica;
import in.demo.order.dao.IOrderRequestRepository;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public class OrderService {


  @Autowired
  private IOrderRequestRepositoryForMain orderRequestRepositoryForMain;

  @Autowired
  private IOrderRequestRepositoryForReplica orderRequestRepositoryForReplica;


  public CustomerVisitsResponse getTotalCustomerVisitsForMonthForReplicaDataSource(Long customerId) {
    List<Integer> statusIdList= new ArrayList<>();
    CustomerVisitsResponse response= new CustomerVisitsResponse();
    statusIdList.add(OrderServiceConstants.SOME_CONSTANT_VALUE);

    List<Integer> sellerIdList= new ArrayList<>();
    sellerIdList.add(OrderServiceConstants.SOME_CONSTANT_VALUE);

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM");
    Date date = new Date();
    String month= dateFormat.format(date)+"%";
    try {
    List<in.demo.order.replicadao.model.OrderEntity> orders =
        orderRequestRepositoryForReplica.getOrderBycustomerIdAndBdMonth(customerId,statusIdList,month,sellerIdList);
    if(orders!=null && !orders.isEmpty())
    {
      double total=0d;
      for(in.demo.order.replicadao.model.OrderEntity order:orders)
      {
        total+=order.getPayableAmount();
      }
      response.setTotalSpent(total);
      response.setTotalVisits((long)(orders.size()));
    }
    else {
      response.setTotalSpent(0d);
      response.setTotalVisits(0l);
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.info("Error occured while fetching getTotalCustomerVisitsForMonth customerid: " + customerId);
      response.setTotalSpent(0d);
      response.setTotalVisits(0l);
      return response;
    }
    return response;
  }


  public CustomerVisitsResponse getTotalCustomerVisitsForMonthForMainDataSource(Long customerId) {
    List<Integer> statusIdList= new ArrayList<>();
    CustomerVisitsResponse response= new CustomerVisitsResponse();
    statusIdList.add(OrderServiceConstants.SOME_CONSTANT_VALUE);

    List<Integer> sellerIdList= new ArrayList<>();
    sellerIdList.add(OrderServiceConstants.SOME_CONSTANT_VALUE);

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM");
    Date date = new Date();
    String month= dateFormat.format(date)+"%";
    try {
      List<in.demo.order.dao.model.OrderEntity> orders =
              orderRequestRepositoryForMain.getOrderBycustomerIdAndBdMonth(customerId,statusIdList,month,sellerIdList);
      if(orders!=null && !orders.isEmpty())
      {
        double total=0d;
        for(in.demo.order.dao.model.OrderEntity order:orders)
        {
          total+=order.getPayableAmount();
        }
        response.setTotalSpent(total);
        response.setTotalVisits((long)(orders.size()));
      }
      else {
        response.setTotalSpent(0d);
        response.setTotalVisits(0l);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.info("Error occured while fetching getTotalCustomerVisitsForMonth customerid: " + customerId);
      response.setTotalSpent(0d);
      response.setTotalVisits(0l);
      return response;
    }
    return response;
  }

}
```

**Repository classes**

`package in.demo.order.replicadao;`
`IOrderRequestRepositoryForReplica`

```
package in.demo.order.replicadao;

import in.demo.order.replicadao.model.OrderEntity;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface IOrderRequestRepositoryForReplica extends PagingAndSortingRepository<OrderEntity, Long> {

    @Query(nativeQuery = true,
            value = "SELECT * FROM orders ...<some query>")
    public List<OrderEntity> getOrderBycustomerIdAndBdMonth(
            Long customerId, List<Integer> statusIdList, String month, List<Integer> sellerIdList);
}
```

`package in.demo.order.dao;`
`IOrderRequestRepositoryForMain`

```
package in.demo.order.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import in.demo.order.dao.model.OrderEntity;

@Repository
public interface IOrderRequestRepositoryForMain extends PagingAndSortingRepository<OrderEntity, Long> {
 
  @Query(nativeQuery = true,
      value = "SELECT * FROM orders ...<some query>")
  public List<OrderEntity> getOrderBycustomerIdAndBdMonth(Long customerId,
      List<Integer> statusIdList, String month, List<Integer> sellerIdList);
}
```

Same Entity in different package with different serialVersionUID

packages are:
`package in.demo.order.replicadao.model;`
`package in.demo.order.dao.model;`

`OrderEntity`

```
package in.demo.order.replicadao.model;


import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class OrderEntity implements Serializable {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4667868888563693990L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String orderId;


    public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getOrderId() {
    return orderId;
}

public void setOrderId(String orderId) {
    this.orderId = orderId;
}

}
```

Controller class
`OrderController`

```
package in.demo.order.controller;

import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import in.demo.order.service.OrderManagerService;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/order")
public class OrderController {

  @Autowired
  private OrderManagerService orderManagerService;

  @Autowired
  private DataSource mainDataSource;

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("replicaDataSource")
  private DataSource replicaDataSource;


  @GetMapping("/replica")
  public CustomerVisitsResponse getCustomerVisitResponseForReplica() {
    Long customerId = 123L;
    return orderManagerService.getCustomerVisitsForMonthForReplicaDataSource(customerId);
  }

  @GetMapping("/main")
  public CustomerVisitsResponse getCustomerVisitResponseForMain() {
    Long customerId = 123L;
    return orderManagerService.getCustomerVisitsForMonthForMainDataSource(customerId);
  }

  @GetMapping("/maindatasource")
  public String getMainDataSource() {
    return mainDataSource.toString();
  }

  @GetMapping("/replicadatasource")
  public String getReplicaDataSource() {
    return replicaDataSource.toString();
  }



}
```

I have checked manually in both Database for the query I am running. Data is present. But when I am running from postman to test
for replica, I am getting
`Method threw 'org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException' exception.` caused by `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query`

for main, I am getting
`Transaction was marked for rollback only; cannot commit; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction was marked for rollback only; cannot commit`

When I am using one datasource, the query is working fine.

Comment: have you tried with just a single datasource ? SQLGrammarException is usually related to the query

Comment: Yes, previously we were using single data source only, and with single data source it is working fine.

Comment: Anyway I got the solution, the issue was Entity column name mapping issue, previously we were not mentioning @Column(name="column_name") , once I added the annotation, it started to work. But still I am confused how it is working fine when using single Data source

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with Entity class column name mapping issue, previously we were not mentioning @Column(name="column_name") , once I added the annotation, it started to work. But still I am confused how it is working fine when using single Data source